# Matrix Lagrange Multiplier with only positive entries

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

The problem is given $g(x) = A^Tx = k$ minimize $f(x) = x^TMx$ and $A$ is a real valued vector, $M$ is a real valued symmetric matrix, and all entries of $x$ must sum to 1. I attempted to use Lagrange multipliers and then solve for each entry in $x$, but because of the quadratic term it seems like the derivative for one entry depends on all of $x$ and I'm not sure if I'm approaching this problem correctly. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the gradient of $x^TMx$ is written as $(M+M^T)x$. The reason is as follows. We first express $x^TMx$ as
$$
x^TMx=\sum_{i,j}m_{ij}x_ix_j,
$$
from which
$$
{\frac{\partial x^TMx}{\partial x_k}
=
\frac{\partial \sum_{i,j}m_{ij}x_ix_j}{\partial x_k}
\\
=
\frac{\partial \sum_{i=k,j\ne k}m_{ij}x_ix_j}{\partial x_k}
+
\frac{\partial \sum_{i\ne k,j= k}m_{ij}x_ix_j}{\partial x_k}
\\
+
\frac{\partial \sum_{i=j=k}m_{ij}x_ix_j}{\partial x_k}
+
\frac{\partial \sum_{i\ne k,j\ne k}m_{ij}x_ix_j}{\partial x_k}
\\
=
\sum_{j\ne k}m_{kj}x_j
+
\sum_{i\ne k}m_{ik}x_i
+
2m_{kk}x_k
\\
=
\sum_{i}(m_{kj}+m_{jk})x_j
\\= (M+M^T)x
}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I don't think this answers how to approach the optimization problem. It's not that the dependence on $x$ in the derivative itself is confusing, but how I can work around that in the problem.

Comment: The approach I mentioned in my answer is a part of addressing the solution by writing the Lagrangian in matrix form and calculating the derivation as a whole, not element by element. The proof I wrote is a toolbox to achieve this. To clarify it more, write $L=x^TMx+\nu(A^Tx-k)+\lambda x$, take derivative with respect to $x$ as a whole, not each $x_i$ and proceed. Feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: Could you explain how you would proceed after taking the derivative, but also I think some of the terms disagree $x^TMx$ and $A^Tv-k$ should be single numbers, but $x$ is a whole vector.

Comment: Actually, there are all scalars, which you can confirm by checking the matrix dimensions. Note that $\nu$ is scalar since we have only one equality constraint and $\lambda$ is a vector (where the term $\lambda x$ in Lagrangian must be replaced by $\lambda^T x$; my mistake). Now we write$$L=x^TMx+\nu A^T x-\nu k+\lambda^Tx$$ and$$\partial L/\partial x=(M+M^T)x+A^T\nu+\lambda=0$$

Comment: Ah okay so it seems that I got the same result as you just with a different order of steps. So here what I get for $x$ is $-(A^Tv-\lambda)M^{-1}/2$, and this is the part where I thought I might have to go element by element.

Comment: You don't have to yet. Now replace the relation you obtained for $x$ in $A^Tx=k$ to get to more results. Do element-wise calculations only if you don't have any other choice. Two more notes: 1-you have assumed $M$ to be symmetric which is ok, and 2-$M^{-1}$ should be multiplied from left side to $A^Tv-\lambda$.

Comment: So doing that I can get $v$ to be $(2k + A^T M^{-1} \lambda)/(-A^T M^{-1} A)$ but I don't think I can solve for $\lambda$ in terms of $v$, and I'm not sure what now. Also how would I be checking that the entries are positive?